# Robots files generation - simplifying foreach code

Tags: php, array

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can simplify this code which is used to generate a robots.txt file with numerous rules.  Different files/folders are separated in separate arrays because they're applied differently but in some cases they are applied the same.  In these cases, rather than write out a separate `foreach` for each one, this is what I'm trying to simplify:

```
<?php

public function generateRobotsFile($rbfile, $smfile) {
    $tab = array();
    $tab['SemBot'] = array('Googlebot',"bingbot\nCrawl-delay: 5",'MSNBot');

    $tab['Lang'] = array('eb');
    $tab['Files'] = array('address.php','cart.php');
    $tab['Folder'] = array('classes','docs','themes');

    fwrite($writeFd, "\nUser-agent: *\n");
    foreach ($tab['Lang'] as $Lang) {
        fwrite($writeFd, 'Disallow: ' . __PS_BASE_URI__ . $Lang . "\n");
    }
    foreach ($tab['Folder'] as $Folder) {
        fwrite($writeFd, 'Disallow: ' . __PS_BASE_URI__ . $Folder . "\n");
    }

    foreach ($tab['SemBot'] as $SemBot) {
        fwrite($writeFd, "User-agent: ' . $SemBot . "\n");
        foreach ($tab['Files'] as $Files) {
            fwrite($writeFd, 'Disallow: ' . __PS_BASE_URI__ . $Files . "\n");
        }
        foreach ($tab['Folder'] as $Folder) {
            fwrite($writeFd, 'Disallow: ' . __PS_BASE_)URI__ . $Folder . "/\n");
        }
    }
```

The arrays must remain separated but in some cases they are looped through the same disallow rule so I'm reaching for a `foreach` array in array but haven't quite grasped it yet.

Comment: There's a couple of syntax errors in this; `"User-agent: '` uses the wrong quote types and a bracket in `__PS_BASE_)URI__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of lines is your primary concern, then really all we can do with this is merge your array creation lines, and use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) to create temporary arrays which you can loop around, like so:

```
public function generateRobotsFile($rbfile, $smfile)
{
    $tab = array('SemBot' => array('Googlebot', "bingbot\nCrawl-delay: 5", 'MSNBot'),
                 'Lang'   => array('eb'),
                 'Files'  => array('address.php', 'cart.php'),
                 'Folder' => array('classes', 'docs', 'themes'));
    fwrite($writeFd, "\nUser-agent: *\n");
    foreach(array_merge($tab['Lang'], $tab['Folder']) as $disallow)
    {
        fwrite($writeFd, 'Disallow: ' . __PS_BASE_URI__ . $disallow . "\n");
    }
    foreach($tab['SemBot'] as $SemBot)
    {
        fwrite($writeFd, "User-agent: " . $SemBot . "\n");
        foreach(array_merge($tab['Files'], $tab['Folder']) as $disallow)
        {
            fwrite($writeFd, 'Disallow: ' . __PS_BASE_URI__ . $disallow . "\n");
        }
    }
}
```